# swift 3.0 converting Ambiguous use of tableView when adding to views dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

Hi I am getting the following error when attempting to add my tableView into a views dictionary for constraints,

> Ambiguous use of 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

The code causing this is

```
let viewsDict = ["panelView": panelView, "tableView": tableView]
```

which I then use to create auto layout constraints

```
scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[tableView]-20-[panelView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[panelView]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
```

The code is called from

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
```

I am currently converting a code base written in swift 2.2 to swift 3.0

Let me know if you need any more information and thanks in advance for your help.

Some more info

I am initialising my table view

```
  let tableView:UITableView = UITableView()
```

and registering delegate, data source and cell as follows

```
tableView.register(TPLShelfLocationTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        refreshData()

tableView.delegate = self

tableView.dataSource = self

tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
```

Comment: There is no outlet the tableview is entirely in code.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly type the Dictionary as `[String: UITableView]`?

Comment: @James Thanks so much this was driving me insane I typed it as [String:UIView] as it needs other views. If you post this as answer I will up vote and mark as accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the type of `viewsDict` as `[String: UIView]`:

```
let viewsDict: [String: UIView] = ["panelView": panelView, "tableView": tableView]
```